# Azure FileProperties content missing on list_directories_and_files

Tags: python, azure-storage, azure-files

I am using Django 2.0.4, Python 3.5 and an Azure FileStorage:

[Azure Python API](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/python/api/azure-storage-file/azure.storage.file.fileservice.FileService?view=azure-python#list-directories-and-files)

[Seems to work with Blobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40976398/how-can-i-extract-last-modified-date-in-ms-azure-for-a-blob-in-my-blob-storage)

Everything is working fine with the Azure Python package. Now I want to list all files of one directory and see their `LastModified` property and some other properties:

```
# getting Azure service
azureService = getAzureService()

# list all files in directory
archivesList = azureService.list_directories_and_files('myfilestoragename', directory_name='archives')
for element in archivesList:
    element_name = element.name
    element_lastmodified = element.properties.last_modified
    element_contentlength = element.properties.content_length
```

The problem is: `element_lastmodified` is always `None`
But `element_contentlength` has a valid value.

When I am using MS Azure Storage Explorer and have a look into the `properties` of each file, the property `LastModified` has a valid timestamp.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

last_modified is always None because unfortunately the service does not return this info when listing directories and files. Please refer to the REST doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-directories-and-files).

To get the last modified time of files/directories, please use get_directory_properties and get_file_properties.

Comment: Thanks for your reference! So I have to use `get_file_properties` for each file in my list - wow that's not referenced in the python api docs. An option to get these information would be nice...